# Input is not being assigned to my variable while using Scanner

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to assign the user's middle name to the variable middleName. When I step through the code The input for middleName is being assigned to lastName. It all goes well until the if statement. Any help?

```
    //New instance of a scanner (keyboard) so users can input information
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create variables
    String firstName;
    String yesOrNo;
    String middleName = null;
    String lastName;

    //Ask user for first name and store input into variable.
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    firstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Ask user if they have a middle name and store input into variable.
    //If not then move to last name
    System.out.println("Do you have a middle name? (Y or N)");
    while(true)
    {            
        yesOrNo = keyboard.next();
        yesOrNo = yesOrNo.toUpperCase();

        if("Y".equals(yesOrNo) || "N".equals(yesOrNo))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I need to know whether you have a middle name. \nPlease tell me whether you have a middle name. \nY or N");
        }                
    }

    if ("Y".equals(yesOrNo))
    {
        //Ask user for middle name and store input into variable.
        System.out.println("What is your middle name?");
        middleName = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    else
    {
        middleName = "";
    }

    //Ask user for last name and store input into variable.
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    lastName = keyboard.nextLine();    


    //Output messages using the variables.
    System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + "!");
    System.out.println("Welcome " + firstName + "!");
    System.out.println("Welcome " + lastName + ", " + firstName + "!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use nextLine() and next() together, you have to make sure to use nextLine() alone right after your next(), otherwise the next line will be skipped.

ex:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner();
String word=s.next();
s.nextLine();
String line=s.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that. To make sure I understand why though, it is because next() starts reading AT the newline (\n) and nextline() will start reading AFTER the newline (\n)

Comment: Not quite. Next() will consume based on the delimiter, while nextline() will consume the entire line, including the newline char. As such, if you use next(), nextLine() right after will see that there's still a \n (and any thing else left on that line) and will consume that rather than the "next line"